# NASM MOV is producing segfault depending on place

Tags: debugging, assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm

I'm making little NASM function to make vertical mirror of pixel table stored in one dimensional vector of bytes with colors arranged like BGRBGRBGR...

I made a prototype which do it for first (last, it's BMP) line. Now i have a problem, why is that version correct, and not producing SEGFAULT:

```
global asm_vert

section     .text

asm_vert:   
            push ebp
            mov ebp, esp
            push ecx
            push esi
            push ebx
            push edx
            push edi

            mov edx, [ebp+8]        ; table width
            mov ecx, [ebp+12]       ; table height
            mov esi, [ebp+16]       ; input table adress
            mov edi, [ebp+20]       ; output table adress

            mov eax, edx
            mov ecx, edx
            mov ebx, 3
            mul ebx
            add edi, eax
            sub edi, 3

x_loop:
            mov bl, byte[esi]
            mov byte[edi], bl
            inc esi
            inc edi
            mov bl, byte[esi]
            mov byte[edi], bl
            inc esi
            inc edi
            mov bl, byte[esi]
            mov byte[edi], bl
            inc esi
            sub edi, 5
            loop x_loop

            pop edi
            pop edx
            pop ebx
            pop esi
            pop ecx
            pop ebp

            ret
```

And if i only edit that section:

```
            mov eax, edx
            mov ecx, edx
            mov ebx, 3
            mul ebx
            add edi, eax
            sub edi, 3
```

To that:

```
            mov eax, edx
            mov ebx, 3
            mul ebx
            mov ecx, edx
            add edi, eax
            sub edi, 3
```

It's not valid. I thought that it's the same thing logically, but it's not if the first version is correct and the second one isn't. And which debugger with graphical interface (Linux) would you recommend for that?

I will be thankful for any advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MUL EBX` stores the product in `EDX:EAX`, so when you place `MOV ECX,EDX` after the `MUL` you're getting the high 32 bits of the product in `ECX` instead of the width.